# Error when installing of VS 2013 (Access denied)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, failed-installation

I'm trying to install VS 2013 RTM on my laptop with Windows 7 (x64) SP1 and at the end it gives the following error.  I've looked at that KB article and it mentions a hotfix that comes with VS 2012 (i don't have it installed on my machine). Any ideas about how to fix it?

[image: Screenshot with error]

Comment: Have you examined to log file?

Comment: Turn off your anti-virus, reboot your machine and try again.

Comment: make sure you are running the process setup.exe as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue during VS 2013 installation on my laptop. In general, even with this issues VS is working well, but VS addons won't see your installation. The reason of such behavior - issue with windows update service.

From my installation log: Error 0x80070005: Failed to open WU service.

Please see article on technet, answer from Della Li: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5728fc8d-4ba7-4d08-994a-2144b79a8f96/windows-update-wont-work?forum=w7itprogeneral

After listed there actions try to repair/reinstall your VS. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

while installing new VS 2015 Enterprise edition on Windows 7 machine, I got below error... it was strange and could not find any help from Googling...
finally saw the log file and search with the KB2999226, it was referring Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu may be did not have access. I did that installation manually and hence it started working.

so manually install the file "Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" from "$VS folder\packages\Patch\x64" .
then run it.